# Referencing 64-bit static library from a 32-bit Xcode project

Tags: c++, xcode, openframeworks, audio-fingerprinting

I'm trying to build an OpenFrameworks project while using the echoprint API in C++ in Xcode. OpenFrameworks requires to be built in i386, but echoprint builds in x86_64.

Is it possible to reference  a 64-bit static library from a 32-bit project? If so, how do I do this within Xcode 4?

Comment: 64-bit and 32-bit code don't mix in a single process.

Comment: Have you tried asking if echoprint can be built 32-bit at the echonest developer forums? They're quite friendly. You're talking about echoprint-codegen, right?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably not possible (at least not on Linux), because the instruction & register sets are different on x86 (32 bits) and x86-64 (64 bits).

Some people managed to make dirty tricks to call 32 bits libraries from 64 bits code on Linux (.e.g. ndiswrapper ...). Details should be very ugly.

I would suggest to make your 32 bit software a different process from the 64 bits one, and use some IPC machinery between them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build echoprint-codegen as a 32-bit executable on Mac OS X and library by adding `-arch i386` to the OPTFLAGS at the beginning of the Makefile and adding a $(CXXFLAGS) on line 24. I use MacPorts and I did need to make sure to build taglib with the universal variant.

I wrote a patch:

```
diff --git a/src/Makefile b/src/Makefile
index 630efb4..1c9b821 100644
--- a/src/Makefile
+++ b/src/Makefile
@@ -2,8 +2,8 @@ UNAME := $(shell uname -s)
 CXX=g++
 CC=gcc
 #OPTFLAGS=-g -O0
-OPTFLAGS=-O3 -DBOOST_UBLAS_NDEBUG -DNDEBUG
-CXXFLAGS=-Wall -I/usr/local/include/boost-1_35 `taglib-config --cflags` -fPIC $(OPTFLAGS)
+OPTFLAGS=-O3 -DBOOST_UBLAS_NDEBUG -DNDEBUG -arch i386
+CXXFLAGS=-Wall -I/usr/local/include/boost-1_35 `taglib-config --cflags` -fPIC $(OPTFLAGS)
 CFLAGS=-Wall -fPIC $(OPTFLAGS)
 LDFLAGS=`taglib-config --libs` -lz -lpthread $(OPTFLAGS)

@@ -21,7 +21,7 @@ MODULES = $(MODULES_LIB) Metadata.o
 all: libcodegen echoprint-codegen

 libcodegen: $(MODULES_LIB)
-   $(CXX) -shared -fPIC -o libcodegen.so $(MODULES_LIB) -lz
+   $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -shared -fPIC -o libcodegen.so $(MODULES_LIB) -lz
 ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
    libtool -dynamic -flat_namespace -install_name libcodegen.4.1.1.dylib -lSystem -compatibility_version 4.1 -macosx_version_min 10.6 \
         -current_version 4.1.1 -o libcodegen.4.1.1.dylib -undefined suppress \
```

which I've stored as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/1407663).